# Want to know how to iterate through SSISDB folders, C#

Tags: c#, ssis

I am trying to write in C# what this powershell script does ( See image ).
Went halfway but not much luck ( I use these namespaces

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using Microsoft.SqlServer;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices;
```

) 
I managed to get my code to work upto the point

```
SqlConnection ssisConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data 
Source=MHPDW2;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;");

IntegrationServices ssisServer = new IntegrationServices(ssisConnection);
foreach ?? ( you continue )
```

But no luck after that how to iterate through each folder. BTW the powershell script works fine with no issues.
Help! Click link below for powershell script code picture

[powerscript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48H61.png)

```
$sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=MHPAPP2;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;" 
$sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $sqlConnectionString 



# Create the Integration Services object 
$integrationServices = New-Object $ISNamespace".IntegrationServices" $sqlConnection 

if ($integrationServices.Catalogs.Count -gt 0)  
{  
    $catalog = $integrationServices.Catalogs["SSISDB"] 

    write-host "Enumerating all folders..." 

    $folders = $catalog.Folders 

    if ($folders.Count -gt 0) 
    { 
        foreach ($folder in $folders) 
        { 
            $foldername = $folder.Name 
            Write-Host "Exporting Folder " $foldername " ..." 

            # Create a new file folder 
            mkdir $ProjectFilePath"\"$foldername 

            # Export all projects 
            $projects = $folder.Projects 
            if ($projects.Count -gt 0) 
            { 
                foreach($project in $projects) 
                { 
                    $fullpath = $ProjectFilePath + "\" + $foldername + "\" + $project.Name + ".ispac" 
                    Write-Host "Exporting to " $fullpath "  ..." 
                    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($fullpath, $project.GetProjectBytes()) 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
} 

Write-Host "All done."
```

Comment: don't screenshot code; include it in the question

Comment: Have you looked at the `Catalogs` property - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.integrationservices.integrationservices.catalogs.aspx ?

Comment: Yes, visited the link, I am a newbie to C#. Can you may be post  a few lines of code and I can get started that way...